# How to discard previous batch aggregated data stored in state folder of checkpoint directory?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark structured streaming job which will fetch data from kafka and using forEachBatch to save data into Neo4j as follows:

```
StreamingQuery query = eventsDf
        .writeStream()
        .queryName("streaming")
        .outputMode("update")
        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(80000))
        .foreachBatch(
                (VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>, Long>) (dfBatch, batchId) -> {
                }
        )
        .option("checkpointLocation", "src/main/resources/checkpoint")
        .start();
```

eventsDf consists of aggregated and filtered data. **(Also, I don't have timestamp column to use window/watermark)**

For 1st batch it will have data and after 80s, there will be a second batch which consists of data of previous batch due to aggregation of `max` function
What I require:

1. Discard previous batch data
2. Size of data present in `State` folder in checkpoint location is continuosly increasing
   `State` folder consists of delta and checkpoint files
   Even if `minDeltasForSnapshot`configuration is applied, files are growing continuously

I tried different spark configurations:

```
"spark.sql.streaming.minBatchesToRetain", 2
"spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.minDeltasForSnapshot", 2
"cleanSource", "delete"
"spark.sql.streaming.forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation", true
```

**Update**:

I have `groupby` and `aggregation` in my code, so I added batchId as new column using `.withColumn()` and then performed `groupby` and `aggregation`. After this change my delta files were not growing continuously (able to solve that), but my `snapshot` files are growing continuously.

How can this be prevented?

Comment: Tried solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132401/spark-structured-streaming-stateless-mode but getting error:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: mapGroupsWithState is not supported with aggregation on a streaming DataFrame/Dataset;

Answer (score 0):

I am storing dummy data in state files (i.e. delta and snapshot files) which will prevent growing my state **(By making these changes spark structured streaming job will be stateless job)**

Below code snippet is inside `forEachBatch` function

```
dfBatch
.groupByKey((MapFunction<Row, String>) (row) -> row.getAs("id"), Encoders.STRING())
.flatMapGroupsWithState(mappingFunction, OutputMode.Update(), Encoders.bean(StateData.class), batchEncoder, ProcessingTimeTimeout())
```

`ExpressionEncoder<Row> batchEncoder = RowEncoder.apply(batchSchema());`
where batchSchema() returns variable with `SchemaType` as datatype

mappingFunction:

```
private FlatMapGroupsWithStateFunction<String, Row, StateData, Row> mappingFunction = (key, value, state) -> {
        if (state.hasTimedOut()) {
            state.remove();
        } else if (state.exists()) {
            StateData existingState = state.get();
            Map<String, Integer> data = existingState.getData();
            int existingCount = data.getOrDefault(key, 0);
            data.put(key, existingCount + 1);
            existingState.setData(data);
            state.update(existingState);
        } else {
            Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(key, 1);
            StateData newState = new StateData(data);
            state.update(newState);
        }
        return value;
    };
```

`StateData` is my class for mapping:

```
package com.spark;

import java.util.Map;

public class StateData {
    Map<String, Integer> data;

    public StateData(Map<String, Integer> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Map<String, Integer> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```